# Excel 2016 - If value on one sheet is present on other, yes or no

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook with two sheets. One sheet is review list, the other is client list.

I want the last column in my `client` sheet to have a formula that looks on the `Review` sheet and display yes or no if the client is present on the `Review` sheet or not. The conditional formatting I know, its whether to use `IF/MATCH/VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Does your sheet have a column that will exactly match another column on the other sheet, or is there more logic involved? Data types matter for some functions.

Comment: Use countif()..

Comment: You could go `IF(COUNTIF()>0` or `IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH())`

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: This is what I compiled so far. The IF statement I want to match the clients name in the Annual Reviews sheet and if true display yes or no. Thanks in advance

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,Annual Reviews!$A:$A,0),"YES"),"NO")

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Review!$A$2:Review!A100,A2)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Hope, this helps you.